# My app will crash as soon as i press on save button

Tags: java, android

```java
public class AddCarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.make)
    EditText make;
    @BindView(R.id.year)
    EditText year;
    @BindView(R.id.model)
    EditText model;
    @BindView(R.id.plate_no)
    EditText plateNo;
    @BindView(R.id.carPhoto)
    ImageView carPhoto;
    @BindView(R.id.save)
    Button save;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;

    String imageStr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_car);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.carPhoto)
    public void onClick() {
        ImagePicker.pickImage(this, "Select your image:");
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.save)
    public void onClickSave() {

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(make.getText().toString())
                || TextUtils.isEmpty(model.getText().toString())
                || TextUtils.isEmpty(plateNo.getText().toString())
                || TextUtils.isEmpty(year.getText().toString())){
            Utils.showToast(AddCarActivity.this,"Please Enter Valid Data");
            return;
        }

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = Utils.showProgressDialog(AddCarActivity.this);

        DatabaseReference feedsRef = database.getReference("cars");
        try {
            Map<String, Object> map =new HashMap<>();
            map.put("make",make.getText().toString());
            map.put("model",model.getText().toString());
            map.put("plateNo",plateNo.getText().toString());
            map.put("year",year.getText().toString());
            map.put("carId", Utils.getUserId(this));
            map.put("carPhoto",imageStr);
            map.put("userId",Utils.getUserId(AddCarActivity.this));
            feedsRef.push().setValue(map).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    AddCarActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
            imageStr=encodeImage(bitmap);
            carPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String encodeImage(Bitmap bm) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return encImage;
    }
}
```

The app will crash as soon as I press on save button. Is there something wrong with my code? I'm quite new in creating apps and I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWYN2.jpg) of the app (blank). And here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ERuW.jpg) demonstrating it in use.

Comment: Can u paste logs we should see the error message in order to answer your question.

Comment: 03-04 21:30:49.617 27026-27026/com.code.zero.drivermechanicsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.code.zero.drivermechanicsapp, PID: 27026
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: MATCH_PARENT is not supported in ConstraintLayout

Comment: at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.validate(ConstraintLayout.java:1826)
                                                                                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:1818)
                                                                                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)

Comment: at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:385)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:757)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)

Comment: I think we need your layout as well

Comment: 03-04 22:25:23.897 12711-12711/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-04 22:25:23.897 12711-12711/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2

Comment: @MechanicGo your code is good your constraint layout has a problem check my answer, hope this help you. let me know if everything fixed

Answer (score 0):

In your ConstraintLayout remove match_parent and try the code below:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```